# How to select objects based on texture data?

Tags: materials, objects, selection-tools

Is there a way to select all objects in a scene that are using a certain texture?

Without differatiating materials, linked or appended data, lost database connection and so on.

**For example:**

I import a scene with a lot of different objects.
Some of them are using the same texture but on different materials.
I'd like to select all the object that are making use of this texture, even if they are located in different materials or lost their connection to the library (linked/appended materials).

*Note: Not sure if what I'm asking for is eligable as one question. Just hoping that there is a simple solution for selecting objects based on texture data.*

Comment: In theory Select Linked via Shift+L in Object mode [is designed to do that](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/selecting/menu.html#select-linked). However I know it to work like you describe only in BI; it didn't do anything in Cycles (as it uses node-based material and thus texture is a node).

Answer (score 1):

In the outliner editor window, at the right hand side of the menu bar, where the default item in the selection window is "all scenes", activate the drop down menu by pressing the arrows at the right side of the button, and select the menu item "data blocks". In the data blocks list, find "textures", and click on the plus-sign-in-a-circle to the left of the entry, and click on that to expand it. This will show all textures in the scene, and allow you to select them, or if not, to at least determine which objects in the scene are using the texture.